# Logcheck is ignoring ignore rules for dovecot-vmm-combination

Tags: email, dovecot, logcheck

I've setup a mail server using postfix + dovecot + vmm on postgres. But for some reason, my custom logcheck rules are getting ignored in some cases. As en example:

```
Feb 23 10:10:36 xxx dovecot: dict: pgsql(127.0.0.1): Connected to database mailsys
```

My logcheck-ignore rule looks like:

```
# Connecting to (vmm)-database
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ dovecot: auth: pgsql\([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\): Connected to database [[:alnum:]]+$
```

When I'm running

```
 logcheck-test -l /var/log/mail.info -r /etc/logcheck/ignore.d.server/local-dovecot-vmm
```

the lines are getting printed out, so IMHO logcheck seems to find the lines with the ignore rule. But when running the cron again, it's not ignored. Any hint maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line from the log file and your regex differ in the word after dovecot. Your log has the term **dict**, but your regex has the term **auth** instead. So you want to adjust your rule maybe to the following:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ dovecot: (dict|auth): pgsql\([[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}\): Connected to database [[:alnum:]]+$
```

Comment: Dammid. Didn't see that. Thanks